# How to test a random uniq values with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this code:

```
def self.generate_random_uniq_code
  code = sprintf("%06d", SecureRandom.random_number(999999))
  code = self.generate_random_uniq_code if self.where(code: code).count > 0
  code
end
```

The goal is create random codes for a new register, the code can't exist already in the registers
I'm trying test this way, but when I mock the SecureRandom it always return the same value:

```
it "code is unique" do
  old_code = Code.new
  old_code.code = 111111
  new_code = Code.new
  expect(SecureRandom).to receive(:random_number) {old_code.code}
  new_code.code = Code.generate_random_uniq_code
  expect(new_code.code).to_not eq old_code.code
end
```

I was trying to find if there is a way to enable and disable the mock behavior, but I could not find it, I'm not sure I'm doing the test the right way, the code seems no work fine to me.
Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Generally, unless you are actually testing a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that you wrote, you're probably testing the wrong behavior. Consider what behavior you're actually trying to test, and examine your alternatives. In addition, a six-digit number doesn't really have enough of a key space to ensure real randomness for most purposes, so you may want to consider something more robust.

### Some Alternatives

One should always test behavior, rather than implementation. Here are some alternatives to consider:

1. Use a [UUID](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid) instead of a six-digit number. The UUID is [statistically less likely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) to encounter collisions than your current solution.
2. Enforce uniqueness in your database column by [adjusting the schema](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity).
3. Using a [Rails uniqueness validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniquenes) in your model.
4. Use [FactoryGirl sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequences-and-associations) or lambdas to return values for your test.

### Fix Your Spec

If you really insist on testing this piece of code, you should at least use the correct expectations. For example:

```
# This won't do anything useful, if it even runs.
expect(new_code.code).to_not  old_code.code
```

Instead, you should check for equality, with something like this:

```
old_code = 111111
new_code = Code.generate_random_uniq_code
new_code.should_not eq old_code
```

Your code may be broken in other ways (e.g. the *code* variable in your method doesn't seem to be an instance or class variable) so I won't guarantee that the above will work, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to add the "eq" to this example here, but it is there indeed ( I already fixed the question),

Comment: About the UUID, unfortunately I can't use for this case, the code must to be numeric and short (6 digits), I know it is a small range, but it is the requirements and I can't change that for now.

Comment: The goal of this method that is inside of the Code class is avoid a new register(new_code) get the same code as a previous register in the database (old_code).
As you can see it creates the random number, and make a check if the code already exist in the database, if it does, it will call the method itself again.

Comment: What I want is force the first SecureRandom to return a number I know, to go into the loops one time, and them call the method again, to ensure the loop will work and will not be stuck in a infinite loop.
Maybe I can add a rescue block to ensure if I don't have more codes available raise a exception instead of try to find a code forever.

Comment: @user2653660 If you don't already have hold of an object for comparison, let Rails or the database enforce uniqueness, and just test that an exception is raised on duplicates. A rescue block with a retry counter is unlikely to cause an infinite loop, but you could test for that in a separate spec.